# Azure Pipeline Triggers in Azure Devops: Trigger a pipeline when another completes not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

For my service I have:

- A yaml build pipeline configured in Azure DevOps
- A yaml deploy pipeline configured in Azure DevOps

My service repo is hosted in Azure DevOps.

I have configured the branch policies so that when a PR is opened, my build job is triggered. I do not want a build happening before this (e.g. on a commit)

I want my deploy pipeline to be triggered by the build job finishing. I have tried many configurations and I have not been able to achieve this. I have also tried configuring from the Azure DevOps UI so that the deploy pipeline listens for the build job completing - doesn't work.

Any help on achieving this (to my mind, very simple!) workflow would be greatly appreciated.

My build yaml has:

`trigger: none`

and this is working fine, being triggered by the branch policy.

My deploy yaml has the following, I am expecting this pipelines section to listen for my build job completing. I am guessing the trigger: none is overriding somehow, because the build trigger is configured in the UI. However, I cannot enable a trigger here, because it causes the pipeline to start when a commit is made, and this pipeline depends on the build job completing.

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-template-repo
      type: git
      name: Templates
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build
      source: my-build-job
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - '*'
        stages:
          - Docker
```

Configuring triggers both in yaml and the Azure DevOps UI

Comment: One thing to check is that the trigger: none line in your deploy YAML is preventing the pipeline from being triggered by the build job completion. You can try removing that line and configuring the trigger directly in the YAML file.

Comment: References:

-   [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#trigger-one-pipeline-after-another)
-   [Configure pipeline resource triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers)
-   [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops#limits-on-the-number-of-scheduled-runs-in-yaml-pipelines)

Comment: @Arko I have tried this configuration, but it causes the pipeline to be triggered on each commit, it doesn't wait for the build completion.

Comment: I am talking about something like this-
trigger:
  dependencies:
    build: 'succeeded'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-template-repo
      type: git
      name: Templates

Here it specifies that the deploy pipeline should be triggered when the build job succeeds. You can replace build with the name of your actual build job. Have you tried in this way?

Comment: Also, I have included the pipeline completion trigger, under the pipelines section see above

Comment: Hi @sigemer, have you checked whether your deploy yaml file is in the default branch of your repo or changed your pipeline's `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` to the branch where your yaml file is located? Did it work for you?

Comment: This works, thank you. I needed to make sure both pipelines were pointed at my feature branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline completion triggers use the `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` setting to determine which branch's version of a YAML pipeline's branch filters to evaluate when determining whether to run a pipeline as the result of another pipeline completing. By default this setting points to the default branch of the repository. See more detailed info from [Branch considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-considerations).

Please check whether your deploy yaml file is in the default branch of your repo. If not, change your pipeline's `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` to the branch where your yaml file is located. For example, if your `deploy.yml` is in the feature branch, then set the `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` to feature.

To change `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds`, go to edit your pipeline, More actions -> Trigger -> YAML.

[image]

[image]

Don't set any triggers in the user interface
[image]